# jQuery this scope inside plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, scope, this

I build jQuery plugin:

```
        (function( $ ){

            var methods = {
                init : function( options ) {
                    $.fn.queryBuilder = $.extend($.fn.queryBuilder, options);

                    return this.each(function(){

                        methods.getValues();

                        var $this = $(this),
                        data = $this.data('queryBuilder'),
                        url  = '/'+methods.createURL.call();

                        if ( ! data ) {
                            $(this).data('queryBuilder', {
                                target  : $this,
                                url     : url
                            });
                        }
                    });
                },
                getURL:function(){
                    alert $(this);
                }
    }
$.fn.queryBuilder = function( method ) {
        if ( methods[method] ) {
            return methods[method].apply( this, Array.prototype.slice.call( arguments, 1 ));
        } else if ( typeof method === 'object' || ! method ) {
            return methods.init.apply( this, arguments );
        } else {
            $.error( 'Method ' +  method + ' does not exist on jQuery.tooltip' );
        }
    };
})
```

When getValues() method is called, alert shows undefined. How to call getValues with scope to the object which my plugin is bound?

Answer (score 0):

There is no `getValues` function in your code, I assume you mean `getURL`. You can set `this` explicitly by using [`.call` *<sup>[MDN]</sup>*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) or [`.apply`  *<sup>[MDN]</sup>*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply):

```
methods.getURL.call(this);
```

That's the same as you do in

```
return methods.init.apply( this, arguments );
```